# jestjs see progress of rest execution

Tags: jestjs

i have test which dynamic and can run 20min
but i am getting output only at the end 
is there any way to see progress ?

my code

```js
describe('scenarios', () => {
  function doTest(path) {
    it(`should pass ${path}`, () => {
      ...
    });
  });
  for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    doTest(i);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no such possibility.

But, since Jest treats files as test suites, you could split your test across separate files, name them accordingly and let them be ran by CLI. I know it can get cumbersome, but at least that's an option.

You can also get some inspiration from `prettier` on how to handle loads of tests with customised functions:
https://github.com/prettier/prettier/blob/master/tests_config/run_spec.js